# JSON Import with Javascript, how to skip deferred exception?

Tags: json, exception, import, deferred

I have written an javascript importer for a external json dataset

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="data.json"></script>

var importData = JSON.stringify(data);
var importCompany = data.report.company.name;

if(importCompany != ''){
   jQuery('.company .name').text(importCompany);
}
```

All working perfectly :D

My issue is when I update the script to read data2.json and data.report.company.name doesn't exist, I get this error in the developer console

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

How do i overcome this issue?

Thanks

EDIT

data.json (external)

```
var data = {
    "report": {
        "company": {
            "name": "XXX"
            "other": "123"
        },
    "information": "GB-0-01777777",
    "references": "2018-06-26T07:48:41.104Z"
}
```

data2.json (external)

```
var data = {
    "report": {
        "company": {
            "other": "123"
        },
    "information": "GB-0-01777777",
    "references": "2018-06-26T07:48:41.104Z"
}
```

Comment: The error sounds like it's actually data.report.company which doesn't exist (or maybe even data.report doesn't exist. You didn't show us the data so we can't be certain. But of course you can look at it to know. Something like this `if (data.report.company) var importCompany = data.report.company.name;` will help - it checks the company object exists before continuing. But if data.report is also missing you'll have to check for that instead

Comment: I've added the data set if that helps?

Comment: Neither of those samples is valid JSON, so it's still unclear. If you re-created these for your question rather than pasting, then compare the to the original and correct them please.